# curl request with spnego authentication fails with "gss_init_sec_context() failed: : Success"

Tags: curl, kerberos

curl request with kerberos authentication fails.

Checking the output with `-v` option, the output says:

```
$ curl -v -u : --negotiate https://URL

...

< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=****; Path=/; HttpOnly
* gss_init_sec_context() failed: : Success
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
* gss_init_sec_context() failed: : Success
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
...
```

I'm using curl 7.29.0 which redirects a spnego request to the real authentication step.
But in this case, it doesn't move on to the next step.

This issue happens in a certain environment.

In other environments, `gss_init_sec_context() failed: : Success` log doesn't appear and authentication is done well.

What could be a problem?

How can I debug deeper?